# How to catch `require()` exception to check if a module is installed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I've been trying for several hours to check if a node package is installed, to adapt the behaviour of my react-native library depending on that.
I've tried a simple try/catch but, I don't know why, the "Unable to resolve module" exception is absolutely not catched.

```
try {
  var Expo = require('expo');
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Module is not installed');
  console.error(e);
}
```

How can I catch the `require()` "Unable to resolve module" exception, or is there any other way to check if a module is installed ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try changing it to `var m = require('module1234')` because AFAIK `module` is a valid module name, so no exception will occur.

Comment: My bad, `module` was just an example, I didn't know it exists. I've updated my example with my real use case. I want to check if the user has the `expo` package installed, but even with the `try…catch` clause, I still have the fatal js red screen with the "Unable to resolve module" exception.

Comment: Lookup require.resolve. I can't test but think it returns null of it cant resolve a module rather than throw an exception. Could be wrong though.

Comment: I have already tested `require.resolve` but it doesn’t work on react native (or do I need a package to use it ?). It gives me `require.resolve is not a function`

Comment: Ok, I thought `module` was the problem, still I tried your code in VS Code and it works as intended. Maybe if you can provide more info about your environment ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for react native environment, since metro packager does fancy stuff with modules that breaks this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

`Require` is synchronous so error handling must follow the conventional Javascript error handling pattern, even though it may seem odd:

```
try {
    var Expo = require('./123/1234/154.js') //obviously not going to work
    console.log("Installed successfully")
}
catch (e) {
    console.log('ERROR: ')
    console.log(e)
}
```

In general you shouldn't use a try catch for this scenario, as you want your application to fail if a module is not properly installed/found.